# Is it possible to scaffold multiple controllers in one command?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, scaffold, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

Using `MvcScaffolding` I can call these powershell commands to scaffold the Controllers and Views automagically.

```
scaffold Controller Products
scaffold Controller Reviews
```

Is it possible to combine the two commands into one? e.g

```
scaffold Controller Products, Reviews
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
PM> $models="Products","Reviews"
```

then to do it `automa<T>ically`,

```
PM> foreach($m in $models) { Scaffold Controller $m }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple scaffold commands in one line

```
Scaffold Controller Products; Scaffold Controller Reviews
```